# How to resize an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I have a sentence of words and I am trying to go through the sentence, storing each of the separate words into dynamically allocated memory, and then storing a pointer to each word in an array of pointers.

I am getting confused as to how to create new spaces in memory and then copy that data into the next bigger array

```
char** str_to_arr_words (char *str) {
  int length;
  char** arr_words;
  int numOfWords;
  //Loop until you've reached the end of the sentence
  while(*str != '\n'){
    //loop until you reach the end of a word
    while(*str != '\0'){
      length++;
      str++;
    }
    //allocate space in memory for the word
    char* word = malloc(length);
    //set str back to the start of the word
    str = str - length;
    //copy the word in the sentence into its own position in memory
    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++){
      word[x] = str[x];
    }
    numOfWords++;
    //increse the size of the array of word addresses by one and put the most recent address in the new array
    char** newArrWords = malloc(numOfWords);
    for(int x = 0; x < numOfWords - 1; x++){
      newArrWords[x] = arr_words[x];
    }
    newArrWords[numOfWords] = str;
    //set str back to the start of the next word (+1 to skip the '\0')
    str = str + length + 1;
    length = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `realloc()` what you're looking for?

Comment: `while(*str != '\0')` That does not find the end of a word. It finds the end of the whole string. Use `while(*str != ' ')` instead (assuming each word is seperated by one space). Better still, use a function like `strtok`. If that still doesn't help then please provide a better problem description than "I am confused". What specific error, incorrect behaviour or problem are you encountering? Also, please show a complete [mre].

Comment: `int length;` should be `int length = 0;` And don't forget to allocate memory for, and write, the string terminator.

Comment: You use `arr_words` uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function can't escape from these `while(*str != '\n')` and `while(*str != '\0')` statements because when I send a string to this function, it finds the end of the string but then it adds nonsense characters to the end of the string so the upper `*str != '\n'` condition can never be false. Then the loop goes inside again and the inner condition is always true too because of these nonosense characters. So I fixed it like;

```
while((*str != '\n') && (*str != NULL)){
    //loop until you reach the end of a word
    while ((*str != ' ') && (*str != '\n') ) {
        length++;
        str++;
    }
...
```

And you didn't initialize `arr_words` and honestly I couldn't understand what this array is supposed to do but I just copied the string into it like;

```
char* arr_words = (char *)malloc(length);
strcpy(arr_words, word);
```

I believe it's a better choice to use `strcpy` other than the loop.
I also did the same thing for `newArrWords`. You can modify it;

```
char* newArrWords = (char *)malloc(numOfWords);
strcpy(newArrWords, str);
```